# SVG to PNG batch conversion

Tags: windows, image-processing, svg, image-conversion, png

Is there any software that would help me convert a large amount of small SVG files to PNG?

It would be great if it would let me specify the color to use for any solid paths in the SVG files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be possible using **[ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)**, which is available cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Windows). This software ships with a bunch of command-line utilities, perfectly fitting your needs.

Let's give me an example: Say you've stored a bunch of your `*.svg` in the current directory, and want to convert them to `*.png` – that would be a one-liner:

```
convert -format png *.svg
```

A more detailed description can be found with the [ImageMagick examples](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#svg), or a simple [Google-search for "imagemagick convert svg to png"](https://www.google.com/search?q=imagemagick%20convert%20svg%20to%20png). As I've not used *ImageMagick* in this manner, I cannot give you the exact parameters for your "color issue" – but I'd wonder if that wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (gratis, available on Linux, Mac, Windows). It has some [export command line options](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html#OPTIONS), e.g.  `inkscape in.svg --export-type=png -o out.png -h HEIGHT -w WIDTH` .

Comment: In case you prefer the dpi setting:                                                                              
`inkscape in.svg --export-type=png -o out.png --export-dpi=DPI`

Comment: I didn't know Inkscape has a CLI, wonderful! I used `inkscape --export-type=png *.svg` to convert all SVG files in the current folder. [The default is 96 dpi](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html#d-DPI---export-dpi-DPI), which was fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Photoshop CC 2015 or higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop):

- non-gratis
- Windows and OS X
- [can open SVG file](https://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2015/12/import-svg-file-into-photoshop-cc.html)
- can be scripted [(relevant Google search)](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&espv=2&q=Photoshop+CC+2015+script)